# How can I make pacman search look better?

Tags: arch-linux, apt, search, pacman

Currently I am using Arch. Pacman is a great package manager but can I make pacman search look better (pacman -Ss). For example if I search for a package it gives me result lik this:

```
extra/foomatic-db-engine 4:20200206-1
    Foomatic - Foomatic's database engine generates PPD files from the data in Foomatic's XML
    database. It also contains scripts to directly generate print queues and handle jobs.
extra/kdav 1:5.89.0-1 (kf5) [installed]
    A DAV protocol implemention with KJobs
extra/print-manager 21.12.0-1 (kde-applications kde-utilities) [installed]
    A tool for managing print jobs and printers
community/blobby2 1.0-4
    A beach ball game with blobs of goo
community/grafana-agent 0.21.2-1
    Grafana Agent is a telemetry collector for sending metrics, logs, and trace data to the
    opinionated Grafana observability stack
community/kdav2 0.4.0-1
    A DAV protocol implementation with KJobs
community/libxmlb 0.3.5-1 [installed]
    Library to help create and query binary XML blobs
community/obs-studio 27.1.3-2 [installed]
    Free, open source software for live streaming and recording
community/parallel 20211122-1
    A shell tool for executing jobs in parallel
```

I search for obs and I got these results, see these results are correct but are inconvenient to find the package and package name.

Whereas apt package manager has a better search:
[image: apt search]

Please help on how I can make pacman search results show in a systematic way.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: if you prefer apt, then why not just switch to a distro based on apt and .deb packages?  there are many to choose from.

Comment: @cas it won't have Arch specific features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with pacman.

```
$ pacman -Ss "http server" | head -n 10 | grep -n ""

1:core/libmicrohttpd 0.9.73-1
2:    a small C library that is supposed to make it easy to run an HTTP server as part of another application.
3:extra/apache 2.4.51-2
4:    A high performance Unix-based HTTP server
5:extra/nginx 1.20.2-1
6:    Lightweight HTTP server and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
7:extra/perl-http-daemon 6.12-1
8:    Simple http server class
9:community/gunicorn 20.1.0-1
10:    WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX
```

```
$ pacman -Ss http server | head -n 10 | grep -n ""

1:core/libmicrohttpd 0.9.73-1
2:    a small C library that is supposed to make it easy to run an HTTP server as part of another application.
3:extra/apache 2.4.51-2
4:    A high performance Unix-based HTTP server
5:extra/libcddb 1.3.2-6.1
6:    Library that implements the different protocols (CDDBP, HTTP, SMTP) to access data on a CDDB server (e.g. http://freedb.org).
7:extra/libsoup 2.74.2-1
8:    HTTP client/server library for GNOME
9:extra/libsoup3 3.0.3-1
10:    HTTP client/server library for GNOME
```

Note that first one doesn't lists `libsoup3` or `libsoup` because they don't have the exact phrase "http server".

Similarly,

```
$ pacman -Ss ^OBS

community/obs-studio 27.1.3-2
    Free, open source software for live streaming and recording
```

vs

```
$ pacman -Ss OBS | head -n 10

extra/foomatic-db-engine 4:20200206-1
    Foomatic - Foomatic's database engine generates PPD files from the data in Foomatic's XML database. It also contains scripts to directly generate print queues and handle jobs.
extra/kdav 1:5.88.0-1 (kf5)
    A DAV protocol implemention with KJobs
extra/print-manager 21.08.3-1 (kde-applications kde-utilities)
    A tool for managing print jobs and printers
community/libxmlb 0.3.5-1
    Library to help create and query binary XML blobs
community/obs-studio 27.1.3-2
    Free, open source software for live streaming and recording
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine